# Is Maven better than the ant building tool for deploy an EAR project

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, ant, gradle

I am now using Ant 1.8 in my EAR project with JBoss 4.0.5
Technology I am using is JEE 1.5 with Struts 1.2

I have 3 Jars deployed in my EAR directory of JBoss.

Currently ant is used for building the project and it takes around 30second to build the 1GB project.

I want to change my building tool from ANT to Maven ?

Will Maven be more help full and faster ?

Comment: It is a matter of tastes, convenience, etc. Also have a look at gradle.

Comment: My experience is only with ant. I prefer to use maven. So you suggest that gradle is better than maven ?

Comment: I don't say it is better, I say that it suits my tastes more; gradle doesn't try and impose its workflow on me and is much more adaptable. But that is _my_ opinion.

Comment: My limited understanding of Gradle is that it isn't as mature as Maven when it comes release deployment, so I'd go with Maven everytime

Comment: You made a typo right? You're using JEE 1.4, given that its JBoss 4.0. No, Maven will not make the build faster. That's not its purpose either.

Comment: Ok. 
With ant, all I need to do is to create a single build file { say build.xml } which deploys my ear module in the distributed folder.

 ant -f build.xml

Will that be easier with this new Maven/Gradle ?

Comment: Not necessarily easier or faster but it will be more powerful and more maintainable with Maven/Gradle. ant is quite basic

Comment: @TitusKurian building a EAR with ANT is as simple as with Maven, what you don't get with ANT, at least not out of the box, is dependency management, which is the big reason to move to Maven or Gradle

Comment: @TitusKurian Please consider commenting, accepting or upvoting my answer because the community stands on users feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in that case, that [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) suits your particular needs better than Maven.

### Faster builds

> Will Maven be more help full and faster ?

**Incremental Builds** is a feature the helps making build faster, but Maven itself doesn't support them. I know there exists some plugins that offers out of the box Incremental Builds but I have not use them.

Instead [Gradle scales very well](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/overview.html#sec%3aspecial_feature_of_gradle) and offers you the state-of-art in incremental building: together with "Incremental builds" the other **Multi-project builds** feature is a big time saver for larger builds.

### Reusing your Ant deploy targets

> I have 3 Jars deployed in my EAR directory of JBoss.

Don't worry if you think that Gradle isn't as mature as Maven when it comes release deployment: [Gradle is the first build integration tool](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/overview.html#sec%3aspecial_feature_of_gradle). You can [reuse your favourite reliabile Ant deploy targets from Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/ant.html#N113D5), and moreover you can extend them by importing them in Gradle and writing the extension directly in the Gradle domain specific language, without touching your Ant script

When will comes more mature days in deploying with Gradle you can modify your task in `build.gradle` deleting the ant deploy target import and using the new deploy gradle plugin: your Gradle task chain will remain the same as it was when you used Ant.